# .net Mobile Application: SDF to SQL Server data sync

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, sdf

I have created a sdf database in a mobile application.

Now I want to synchronize that database to a sql server database.

Comment: I think you'll need to describe your problem in more details if you want to get some answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just like most clients you can use either [Remote Data Access (RDA)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259792(SQL.90).aspx) or [Merge Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172367.aspx).  Microsoft [Sync Services](http://keithelder.net/blog/archive/2007/09/23/Sync-Services-for-SQL-Server-Compact-Edition-3.5-in-Visual.aspx) is also an option.